# Remove first occurrence that matches criteria from a list

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of strings:

```
first item
second item
# first commented item
third item
# second commented item
```

How do I remove the first item that starts with `#` from the list?

Expected result:

```
first item
second item
third item
# second commented item
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> items = ["First", "Second", "# First", "Third", "# Second"]
>>> for e in items:
...     if e.startswith('#'):
...             items.remove(e)
...             break
... 
>>> items
['First', 'Second', 'Third', '# Second']
```

Comment: Using `for i, e in enumerate(items)` and `items.pop(i)` would make it slightly more efficient.

Comment: @Sven: timeit values: 1.2 sec for `for e in items` and 1.7 sec for `enumerate`.

Comment: @jackson: Does optimization matter? I didn't even aim for that, I focused on readability more than anything :-)

Comment: Try it on a long list where the first item starting with `#` is close to the end.  This is the only case which performance matters for.

Comment: You're modifying the list you're iterating over. In this case it's ok since you immediately break, but it's a very bad idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
items = ["First", "Second", "# First", "Third", "# Second"]
for i in xrange(len(items)):
    if items[i][0] == '#':
        items.pop(i)
        break
print items
```

Comment: This will fail if there are empty strings in the list.

Comment: Just use `items[i].startswith('#')` instead.